# What's the formula- Max A, minimize B, hour restraint.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

We have a target of work that must be attained given restrained available hours.

The target of work that must be completed in a given day is $C=200$.
An $A$ unit of work is more valued (and meaningful) than a $B$ unit of work (max out $A$ before maxing out $B$ to hit target). 
$A+B=200$.  
Daily hours available $=100$. 
$A=1$hr, $B=1/3$hr. Max $A=100$, Max $B=300$.

Fiddling around with it I find the optimal solution is $A=50, B=150$. But this isn't a formula. What is the formula to find $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for any given choice of hours for $A,$ find the number of hours for $B$ such that $100$ hours are filled. This gives an expression of the hours of $B$ in terms of the hours of $A.$ Substitute that expression into $A+B=200$ and solve for the hours for $A.$

Comment: If there are more than 100 hours available, this formula adds additional B instead of maximizing A, therefore surpassing the c=200. any ideas?

Comment: Currently A= C/4 and B=A*3 and C=200

Comment: The conditions $A+B=200$ and $A+B/3=100$ completely determine $A$ and $B,$ there is no optimization to be done. And that is not going to change if you replace the $200$ or the $100$ by other values.